# Java EE: Avoid session-sharing in multi tab browser opening the same application

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, struts

I have an already built large web application (more than 2000 JSPs and 7000 classes) and I need to find a doable method to manage multi sessions

I can't send the parameter JSESSIONID as this will be a massive change for me.

Any Ideas ?

Btw the application has been built on servlets and struts 1.

Comment: Normally switching to URL based sessions rather than cookie sessions is a simple web server settings change.  What is depending on the presence of a cookie?

Comment: @brettw A lot of developers I see don't compose their URL's correctly in JSP and servlets, so the JSESSIONID won't get added throughout the application